# Change state of js/jquery with url string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to change the state of the `.hide()` function based on a URL string or something? Basically I have the following script which shows a sign up form and when you click login the login form displays and the sign up form disapears. I'd like to give a link to current users that shows the login form first. Is there a way to do that with a url string? Or am I stuck?

I have to use js/jquery.

```
$(function () {
    $("#oo-loginContainer").hide();
    $(".link1, .link2").bind("click", function () {
        $("#form-content, #oo-loginContainer").hide();    
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "link1"){
            $("#form-content").show();
        } else  { 
            $("#oo-loginContainer").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can do this. Many frameworks support the HTML5 history api. [History.js](http://browserstate.github.io/history.js/demo/) is an example.

Comment: I'm under the impression there is no support for ie?

Comment: @OneEightLeft nope its cross browser - even works without the history api.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Let's assume that the URL is `www.google.com?foo=bar`

That would give you:

```
console.log(getParameterByName('foo')); //bar
```

Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: well I get where you are going with that but my if statement would have to call the function of showing the login and the else would have to be another function showing the sign up. That seems pretty heavy and I'm not sure how the supported css would look... I'll play around with the idea and see if i can make it make more sense.

Comment: @OneEightLeft Could be as simple as `$('#LoginForm').toggle(getParameterByName('foo'))`, or something similar. If the querystring isn't defined, it will evaluate to false, hence hiding the form.

Comment: where would you put my existing script?

Comment: @OneEightLeft What browsers do you need to support? IE7?

Comment: at least ie8, ie7 would be nice but i'm not going to care that much

Comment: @OneEightLeft Well, just replace `#LoginForm` with whatever elements you want to toggle the visibility on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41638/discussion-between-oneeightleft-and-johan)